# Show tasks during orgmode scheduling

Tags: org-mode, calendar, diary

I am using OrgMode to schedule appointments and tasks. For a simple scheduled event like a phone call, I usually add a simple timestamp by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. Then the cursor is moved to the minibuffer and a calendar pops up in which I can easily move with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the cursor keys. Also, since I add the line

```
%%(org-diary :timestamp :sexp)
```

in my diary file, the dates where I do have appointments are highlighted.

However, I found no way to open a buffer that shows me the scheduled appointments for that day when using the scheduling features of OrgMode (moving through the calendar by using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key etc.). The usual command in the calendar which is invoked by pressing <kbd>d</kbd> does not work, because the cursor is in the minibuffer. How can I get this view, when using the OrgMode scheduling features?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually really easy: Just press <kbd>!</kbd> and you are done. But it was just by accident that I found the solution... Now I can really use emacs-orgmode to schedule my meetings and get a cool overview over the appointments on the dates!

Comment: You might want to mention what `!` is bound to and what it does (e.g. `C-h k !`).